# putting a series of php variables in a sql query?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to put a series of php variables in a sql query.

The way I understand it, it should look like this

```
        Db_DbHelper::query('insert into shop_order_notifications(order_id, message, created_at)
        values ('.$order->id.','.$message.','.$emailPubDate.')' );
```

However, it's not working for some reason. All the variables and database columns are there, and when I replace the PHP variables with simple strings for just testing, they work.

Can anyone tell me if this is the right syntax or not?

Thank you

Comment: You need to enclose the string data in quotes.

Comment: everything in the comment is totally fine, however, for comfort reasons, you may also do this: `Db_DbHelper::query("insert into shop_order_notifications(order_id, message, created_at)
        values ('{$order->id}','{$message}','{$emailPubDate}')" );`

Comment: Take a look at prepared statements, they prevent a lot of problems and headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing the quotes..

```
Db_DbHelper::query('insert into shop_order_notifications (order_id, message, created_at)
        values ("'.intval($order->id).'", "'.addslashes($message).'", "'.addslashes($emailPubDate).'")' );
```

Comment: addslashes maybe in case the message contains double quotes ?

Comment: I don't know if the variable already has double quotes.. i'm assuming that didn't work because of the quotes.

Comment: Yes that's right, but your query won't work if the `$message` variable contains a `"` I've edited it, and upvoted, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Please don't use addslashes in SQL queries. [There is a reason the SQL functions provide their own functions for this](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string).

Comment: Thanks, it got rid of the error but the query is not working (the table is not getting the new rows). All the variables contain simple strings with no quotation marks. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Echo the query and try to run it directly in you database and check out the error

Comment: Correction: the initial answer worked - 
  Db_DbHelper::query('insert into shop_order_notifications(order_id, message, created_at) 
values ("'.$order->id.'", "'.$message.'", "'.$emailPubDate.'")' );

Thanks rennyrocha

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to this

```
$id=$order->id;
Db_DbHelper::query('insert into shop_order_notifications(order_id, message, created_at)
        values ('$id','$message','$emailPubDate')' );
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the answer. Yes like Gerald said it's getting the syntax error (red underline), and returns an error when it is loaded in the page. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: No need to try, it's still invalid.

Comment: Hmm still the same error. Apparently it's not because of the ->.

Comment: echo the query and check whether you are getting all values or not.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to confirm whether the SQL syntax error or other？ get php error log.

you can test it :

```
Db_DbHelper::query("insert into shop_order_notifications(order_id, message, created_at) values ({$order->id},'{$message}','{$emailPubDate}')" );
```

Comment: it gets red underline on the { right before $message

Comment: echo "insert into shop_order_notifications(order_id, message, created_at) values ({$order->id},'{$message}','{$emailPubDate}')";  print ??